# Spotlight: Unable to index network SMB share

Tags: spotlight, smb

I'm trying to turn on spotlight for my NAS drive. I have it mounted in OSX 10.8.2 as the following:

```
 /Volumes/Trogdor (smbfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by soltrain)
```

mdutil returns the following:

```
mdutil -as (removed non relevent parts)
/Volumes/Trogdor:
    Indexing and searching disabled.
```

When I try to enable it I get the following:

```
Noahs-MacBook-Air:~ soltrain$ mdutil -i on /Volumes/Trogdor/
                              /Volumes/Trogdor:
                                  Indexing and searching disabled.
```

I've looked for a .metadata_never_index file on /Volumes/Trogdor/ but do not see any such file. I've also added/removed the volume from the privacy preferences in the spotlight pref panel with no effect. Any ideas? I'd rather not use a separate util if spotlight should be working.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to System Preferences -> Spotlight -> Privacy, then adding in the share to the list not to index, then removing it again. It helped with a similar issue I had.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually enable spotlight on smb mounted volumes in Mountain Lion.

Try 'mdutil -as /Volumes/Trogdor' - you should win indexing :)

Comment: Gah. ignore me - sorry!

Comment: Did you mean to delete this answer entirely or how are we supposed to interpret the comment?

Answer (score -1):

try `mdutil -i` on /Volumes/Trogdor

Comment: Please see my original question for the result of this command